# Handling filenames that contains a hyphen, within a script

Tags: shell, options

I have few files that was incorrectly encoded, during extraction, file names now become something similar to `-a -b`,

Now I'm trying to fix this issue with:

`convmv -f ENCODING -t utf8 --notest *`

But got:

```
Unknown option: a
Unknown option: b
```

So what's the right way to handle it, in a script ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `-a` and `-b` start with `-` the command thinks they are options. To prevent that stick a `--` before the list of filenames like this:

```
convmv -f ENCODING -t utf8 --notest -- *
```

That way everything after `--` will be treated as regular arguments without trying to process them as options.

This is common in a lot of unix commands.